# bypass funcaptcha on twitter

Tags: python, selenium, twitter, captcha

I have a problem with bypass Arkoselabs Funcaptcha with selenium on Twitter page.

I cant submit token because there is not any submit button.

When I try to paste token and just click random pictures I get wrong answer error.
I also tried to solve captchas by getting captcha picture and instructions, request something like 2captcha and click on images. It worked before, but now there is new type of captcha with arrows. When I did the same things I just get wrong answer from 2captcha.

Do you know what should I do?

Comment: by the way, I also tried 2captcha, anycaptcha and anticaptcha extensions, but no one doesn't work with twitter

Comment: @СергейКох 
I have arkose labs public key, surl and page url.

I making a request for 2captcha's api, and get token for captcha. 
smth like `"3084f4a302b176cd7.96368058|r=ap-southeast-1|guitextcolor=%23FDD531|......`

I put it into element with name "fc-token". What I need to do to send callback to solve the captcha?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

c# code. Similar to this in Python

```
 var captchaToken =   "3084f4a302b176cd7.96368058|r=ap-southeast-1|guitextcolor=%23FDD531|......";   
 ((IJavaScriptExecutor)chrome).ExecuteScript("parent.postMessage(JSON.stringify({eventId:'challenge-complete',payload:{sessionToken:'" + captchaToken + "'}}),'*')");
```

Comment: Can you elaborate please, how did you make it work ? like what is `parent` ?